# How to solve "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." error for Class-based APIView Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, django-class-based-views

I am using Django REST Framework and following this tutorial for retrieving all users when admin user is authenticated.

[Class-based APIView of Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/)

I am using Postman to test and trying to retrieve the list of all users registered in the system.

At first I try to use my "User Login with Token" API in Postman to create the necessary token as shown below:

[image: User Login with Token]

I copied the value of the "token" key and pasted it as the value of the "Authorization" key in the "Headers" section of "Get All Users" API in Postman as shown below. It is a GET request and I get the error `"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."` as the response.

[image: Get All Users]

Necessary code snippets are as follows:

**views.py**

```
class UserAccountListView(APIView):
"""
    List of All Users in the System / Application
    * Requires Token Authentication.
    * Only Admin Users are able to access this view.
"""
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
permission_classes = (IsAdminUser, )

def get(self, request, format=None):
    """
        Returns a List of All Users
    """
    full_names = [user.full_name for user in UsersAccount.objects.all()]
    return Response(full_names)
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=30),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": False,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": False,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": True,

    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": None,
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,

    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer", ),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",

    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken", ),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",

    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",

    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', UsersAccountAPIOverview.as_view()),
    path("all", UserAccountListView.as_view()),
    path("register", UsersAccountRegistrationView.as_view()),
    path("token", UserAccountTokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path("token/refresh", TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
    path("token/verify", TokenVerifyView.as_view()),
]
```

Looking forward for your kind support and help. If you need further information, I will provide you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your views.py remove the line:

```
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
```

This is because in your settings.py file, the first line:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ...
],
```

mentions JWTAuthentication and not TokenAuthentication

Answer (score 2):

You must add Bearer in postman :

"Authorization" : "Bearer [token]"

[image: postamn token]

Comment: I have added "Bearer" before token as you mentioned but it is showing the same  error message `"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

Comment: Try changing `Bearer` to `Token`, so `Token ej...`

Comment: @BrianDestura I get this following error if I change from `Bearer` to `Token` as you mentioned. `WrappedAttributeError at /api/users/all
type object 'Token' has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'`

Comment: Looks like progress :) can you share the full traceback?

Comment: /Users/jeetkhondker/.local/share/virtualenvs/codebase-rrBE4nFM/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/authentication.py, line 201, in authenticate_credentials
token = model.objects.select_related('user').get(key=key) 

Variable Value
key 
'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjU1MjQ4Njg5LCJpYXIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MX0.SkJhEJv451LgrEsb-mldDjewlMaeRJZS8NPzAdCo2KI'
model 
<class 'rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token'>
self 
<rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication object at 0x109f2d600>

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
```

use

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
```

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation?

Comment: using JWTAuthentication instead of TokenAuthentication, will allow you to use simpleJwt authentication, not DRF authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Django on Apache using mod_wsgi you have to add

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

in your httpd.conf

Comment: This helped me. I added this line in 000-default.conf. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with postman, but when I tried it using Python requests and including the token in the header, it worked fine.

```
import requests
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token 5a96b81e073c1cf052cf385187b1f299677de386f74b566c6cfcd5287aeac8d4'}

res = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/test/', headers=headers)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using cookiecuter + django and it's awesome as well as a kick on your butt. jaja but since I was interesting on going on with my project I just commented this lines at base.py (in your case it would be at settings.py)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
    # "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    # "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
),
# "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
"DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema",
}
```

and this worked for me just to test my endpoints out, I know it is not the best way but works, I'll update my answer later with a better aproach.